# A non well formed numeric value encountered laravel time calculate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hello i'm try to calculate the duration but it don't work

this is my controller function :

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pan = New Pan();
    $pan->startime = $request->input('startime');
    $pan->endtime = $request->input('endtime');
    $pan->duration = ($request->input('endtime') - $request->input('startime'));
    $pan->save();
    return redirect()->route('pan.index');
}
```

Comment: "it don't work" is not a valid problem statement.  Please describe what the expected result is, what actually _is_ happening, how the two differ, and what debugging you have already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may mean that your `endtime` and `startime` values are strings, which cannot be subtracted. If they are well-formed date/time strings, you should be able to do this:

```
$pan->duration = strtotime($request->input('endtime')) - strtotime($request->input('startime'));
```

The function `strtotime` will convert your strings into integer timestamps, and the resulting `duration` will be in units of seconds.

Comment: this is what it saved in database i don't understand why :/
start time  16:00:00 |
end time 16:30:00 | 
duration  00:18:00 |

Comment: The result of the subtraction is 1800 seconds, which is 30 minutes.